# Can we derive the standard normal distribution function from specification of convolution?

Tags: normal-distribution, convolution, differential-equations

In [this article](https://www.quora.com/q/bzxvjykyriufyfio/What-is-math-pi-math-and-while-were-at-it-whats-math-e-math), the following is said:

> Why is the normal distribution so important? Because it is its own
>   convolution with itself, is why. If you average many similar things,
>   what you get has to be a fixed point of the "averaging" operation,
>   which for a probability density function is the same thing as taking a
>   convolution with itself. And that fixed point is the normal
>   distribution (under some technical conditions), and it also maximizes
>   the entropy for the same reason, and so on.
>
> This feature of the distribution can be formalized as, of course, a
>   differential equation: ′()+()=0.

How do we use the fact that $f$ is the convolution-preserving map to get to the above differential equation?

Comment: You can't.  The quotation merely gives one property of the Normal distribution (family) that is shared by many other distributions, the *stable* distributions.  The second paragraph does not follow from the first.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks, but are there special conditions that make the normal distribution unique among the class of stable distributions? In other words, why does only the normal distribution come up in the central limit theorem?

Comment: It has finite variance.